# A variant of the Laplace principle

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, large-deviations

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$In $\R^d$ I am given a sequence of smooth functions $f_\eps(x)$ that converges uniformly to some $f(x)$, which is assumed to be a *good rate function* in the language of Large Deviation theory (i-e lower semi-continuous with compact sublevelsets).
Let also $g(x)\geq 0$ be a (reasonably smooth) function, possibly vanishing on some "bad set" $Z\subset \R^d$.

I am interested in the following variant of the [Laplace principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_principle_(large_deviations_theory)#Statement_of_the_result):

> If $A\subset \R^d$ is such that
> $$
> \inf\limits_{x\in A} f=\min\limits_{x\in A} f
> \qquad
> \mbox{ is not attained on }Z
> $$
> and
> $$
> \int_A\frac{e^{-f(x)}}{g(x)} \mathrm d x<\infty
> $$
> then
> $$
> -\eps\log \int_A\frac{e^{-\frac{f_\eps(x)}{\eps}}}{g(x)} \mathrm d x
> \xrightarrow[\eps\to 0]{} \min\limits_{x\in A} f.
> $$

Is this statement known, or any stronger version implying it? I have checked some classical textbooks (e.g. Dembo–Zeitouni) but to no avail.
I have a sketch of proof, which I will not write in details here, but just to convince people out there let me just give the big picture: If $g(x)\equiv 1$ has no poles then the uniform convergence $f_\eps\to f$ easily allows one to reduce to the usual Laplace principle.
The presence of poles $x\in Z$ for $g$ may seem bad at first sight, but the fact that $f$ attains its minimum outside of $Z$ essentially means that $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ can be considered as a mere multiplicative prefactor in the Large Deviation Principle (i-e where $e^{-\frac{f_\eps}{\eps}}$ is not "too small", when looked at in the right $\eps\log $ scale).
The $\frac 1g$ term can therefore be omitted and one thus directly reads off the rate function $f(x)$.
I hope this is clear enough, otherwise I'll be happy to try and provide a more rigorous and complete argument.

Comment: If $g$ is nonnegative, can't you just write $\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{e^{\log (g(x))}}$ and apply standard Laplace principle?

Comment: I never thought of it that way, but the problem is still the poles in some sense: in the new exponential rate one has then $\epsilon\ln g(x) + f_\epsilon(x)\approx f(x)$, so it seems legitimate to believe the statement. However the "$\approx$" convergence may not be uniform or anything because of the poles, and it is not clear to me how to directly reduce to a standard application of Laplace's lemma?